# Printing a JPG as a gift

Tags: printing

I want to print a picture for my dad, who loves history, as a gift. I'm worried the file is kinda low quality, but I'm not sure.

[image]
It's 720x900 and 255 kB.

Now, to keep the ratio can I just transpose the pixel ratio to mm? For instance 500x625?

At that size, will the picture still look good?

Comment: Hi! at 500x625mm, one pixel will fill one square mm... That will most certainly not look very pleasing

Comment: I've never actually done this, so not an answer. But you might try using Photoshop (or another similar program, such as the free GIMP) to convert it (in the best available resolution) to a vector graphic image, which would upscale for printing much better than a raster image.

Answer (score 5):

Use a reverse image search like [Tineye.com](https://tineye.com/search/b1265515bbced8af701896fa9aa41316dc967ff1?sort=size&order=desc&page=1) to look for larger versions of that photo.

Here is one that is slightly larger at 1024 x 1346, 332.3 KB

[image]